# Executing query from Prestashop to external database

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to connect from **Prestashop to external database** (ERP) to get the order history from it.

I've cloned the History controller and named it "**residui**".

I've created **ResiduiController.php** that contains:

```
class ResiduiControllerCore extends FrontController {
public $auth = true;
public $php_self = 'residui';
public $authRedirection = 'residui';
public $ssl = true;

public function setMedia() {
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->addCSS(array(
        _THEME_CSS_DIR_.'residui.css',
    ));
    $this->addJS(array(
        _THEME_JS_DIR_.'history.js',
        _THEME_JS_DIR_.'tools.js' // retro compat themes 1.5
    ));
    $this->addJqueryPlugin('footable');
    $this->addJqueryPlugin('footable-sort');
    $this->addJqueryPlugin('scrollTo'); } 

public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    $residui = Order::getCustomerResidui($this->context->customer->id);

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'residui' => $residui
    ));

    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'residui.tpl');   }   }
```

I've inserted the **class getCustomerResidui in Order.php:**

```
public static function getCustomerResidui($id_customer, $showHiddenStatus = false, Context $context = null) {
    if (!$context)
        $context = Context::getContext();
    $evadi = 'S';
    $stato = 'GENERATO';
    $resi = Db::getFromGazie()->executeS("
    SELECT *
    FROM "._GAZ_PREFIX_."tesbro
    WHERE id_cli_presta = '".(int)$id_customer."' AND status =  '".$stato."'
    ORDER BY id_tes DESC");
    if (!$resi)
        return array();

    foreach ($resi as $key => $val) {
        $resi2 = Db::getFromGazie()->executeS("
            SELECT *
            FROM "._GAZ_PREFIX_."rigbro
            WHERE id_doc = '".$val['numdoc']."' AND evadi <> '".$evadi."'
            ORDER BY codart DESC LIMIT 1");

        if ($resi2)
            $resi[$key] = array_merge($resi[$key], $resi2[0]);  }
    return $resi;   }   }
```

I've **added the getFromGazie instance in DB.php** and all **connection parameters to the external DB in settings.inc.php**, such as GAZ_PREFIX, etc.

DB.php:

```
public static function getFromGazie($master = true) {
    static $id = 0;

    // This MUST not be declared with the class members because some defines (like _DB_SERVER_) may not exist yet (the constructor can be called directly with params)
    if (!self::$_servers)
        self::$_servers = array(
            array('gaz_server' => _GAZ_SERVER_, 'gaz_user' => _GAZ_USER_, 'gaz_password' => _GAZ_PASSWD_, 'gaz_database' => _GAZ_NAME_), /* MySQL Master server */
        );

    Db::loadSlaveServers();

    $total_servers = count(self::$_servers);
    if ($master || $total_servers == 1)
        $id_server = 0;
    else {
        $id++;
        $id_server = ($total_servers > 2 && ($id % $total_servers) != 0) ? $id % $total_servers : 1;    }

    if (!isset(self::$instance[$id_server]))    {
        $class = Db::getClass();
        self::$instance[$id_server] = new $class(
            self::$_servers[$id_server]['gaz_server'],
            self::$_servers[$id_server]['gaz_user'],
            self::$_servers[$id_server]['gaz_password'],
            self::$_servers[$id_server]['gaz_database']);   }

    return self::$instance[$id_server]; }
```

The template, **residui.tpl:**

```
<div class="block-center" id="block-history">
    <table id="order-list" class="table table-bordered footab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="first_item" data-sort-ignore="true">{l s='Order reference'}</th>
                <th class="item">{l s='Date'}</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {foreach from=$residui item=residuo name=myLoop}
                <tr class="{if $smarty.foreach.myLoop.first}first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.myLoop.last}last_item{else}item{/if} {if $smarty.foreach.myLoop.index % 2}alternate_item{/if}">
                    <td class="history_link bold">
                        <p class="color-myaccount">
                            {$residuo['numdoc']}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="history_date bold">
                    {$residuo['datemi']}
                    </td>

                </tr>
            {/foreach}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="block-order-detail" class="unvisible">&nbsp;</div>
```

The problem is that **I don't get any line displayed** (I also tested the query manually in PhpMyAdmin).

I tried for hours but I can't see the mistake (and I'm sure I did one or more).

Can you tell me something? Thanks...

Comment: okay, step by step did you any debug? `getFromGazie` return correct instance? `var_dump(Order::getCustomerResidui($this->context->customer->id));` result? also in `config/defines.inc.php` set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);` to see errors directly on page

Comment: Thank for the answer. I did'nt knew the PS_DEV_MODE, now i tried to change `var_dump(Order::getCustomerResidui($this->context->customer->id));` with `$this->context->smarty->assign(array('residui' => Db::getFromGazie()->executeS("SELECT * FROM "._GAZ_PREFIX_."tesbro WHERE id_cli_presta = '".$id_customer."' 
  AND status =  'GENERATO'
  ORDER BY id_tes DESC")));` and the result is an empty line. The problem is that getFromGazie tries to execute the query from Prestashop's DB...I don't understand why!

Comment: Here's the debug result: **Table 'vhsxxxx_yyyyyy.gaz_001tesbro' doesn't exist** but the getFromGazie _GAZ_SERVER is **vhsxxxx_zzzzzz.gaz_001tesbro**

Answer (score 2):

Got it!!!!

First of all thanks to Sergii P that suggests me _PS_MODE_DEV_ that I didn't know...

The problem was that it was always trying to execute the query on the same DB. To solve that, i added _GAZ_NAME_ before _GAZ_PREFIX_, like this:

```
public static function getCustomerResidui($id_customer, $showHiddenStatus = false, Context $context = null)
{
    if (!$context)
        $context = Context::getContext();
    $evadi = 'S';
    $stato = 'GENERATO';
    $resi = Db::getFromGazie()->executeS("
    SELECT *
    FROM "._GAZ_NAME_."."._GAZ_PREFIX_."tesbro
    WHERE id_cli_presta = '".(int)$id_customer."' AND status =  '".$stato."'
    ORDER BY id_tes DESC");
    if (!$resi)
        return array();

    foreach ($resi as $key => $val)
    {
        $resi2 = Db::getFromGazie()->executeS("
            SELECT *
            FROM "._GAZ_NAME_."."._GAZ_PREFIX_."rigbro
            WHERE id_doc = '".$val['numdoc']."' AND evadi <> '".$evadi."'
            ORDER BY codart DESC LIMIT 1");

        if ($resi2)
            $resi[$key] = array_merge($resi[$key], $resi2[0]);

    }
    return $resi;
}
```

Et voilà, everything works fine!